# Amazon EC2 .htaccess 500 internal error

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 instance with a simple PHP website. It works perfectly fine on my local PHP server but when viewing on the AWS I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I think there is something wrong with my htaccess file but I cant figure it out.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.html  application/index.php?key=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^$  application/index.php?key=index  [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

When I comment out the last 2 lines I don't get the error but I still need this to access my php code.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Is your htaccess checked into git? I had a similar problem with elastic beanstalk that meant the Htaccess wasn't being uploaded

Comment: I am not using git on this instance. Just using FTP to get my files up to the server for now. I tried recreating the above .htaccess in the terminal window using vim.

Comment: Your rules don't look right. You are rewriting `.html` URIs to `application/index.php` and then adding `.html` again.

Comment: Hi anubhava, yes my htaccess is removing the .html from the template files so they can be accessed without the .html. As I said above, it works fine on my local MAMP server but not on AWS. Which lines do you think I should correct?

Comment: In that case what is `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]` doing?

Comment: That line should be removing the .html from my URL. Before I had pages like contact.html and they get rewritten to simply contact instead. Is the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed few common issues
>
> 1. Make sure mod_rewrite enabled in apache configuration.

```
#On ubuntu os you can try it like this 
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

> 2. Check the website's main Apache configuration file. For the main domain on a server, this will typically be:
>
> Ubuntu and Debian: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
>
> CentOS 7: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">    
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

> 3. If still you are facing same issue then delete your .htaccess file and create it again from command becuase some time character encoding issue of file lead to such type of issues. For example in your apache log you may see such type of error
>
> /.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf##', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
>
> To resolve this type of character encoding issue go to  your root directory after deleting .htaccess file and create this file again as :

```
nano .htaccess
# or you can use any other editor like ## vi .htaccess
```

> Now put your .htaccess file code in opend file.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html$  application/index.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^$  application/index.php?key=index [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: This works as expected on my local MAMP server but still produces a 500 error on the AWS server. I editted the httpd.conf file via terminal (sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) to allowOverride All within the root folder module but still no luck

Comment: You will need to check Apache error.log on server to see what error you're getting for 500. Without knowing actual error it is difficult to guess why it works on one Apache but doesn't work on other Apache.

Comment: I will have a look. If I find the solution i will post back here. Thank you very much for your time taking a look at this with me.

Comment: I managed to get the error log file open but it doesnt reveal any information I can make sense of. Note that I changed my directory to 'app' instead and amended htaccess to reflect that. Below are some samples from the log file:

Comment: [Wed Jul 15 10:08:08 2015] [error] [client 89.248.24.133] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/app/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Hmm fatal PHP error can surely cause 500. You will need to investigate why is this PHP error coming.